# What does the quarry do when it hits an unknown ore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have BuildCraft and IndustrialCraft2 installed, so I was wondering if I were to build a quarry would it crash when it hit an IC2 ore like copper or tin?

Answer (score 3):

The buildcraft quarry obtains as a block **any** item it runs into, through the same code as mining with a diamond pick. If you can mine it, you can quarry it. Bedrock and other unbreakable blocks cannot be broken by the mining action of the quarry. The only things to be careful of are things that don't drop anything (like spawners) which are simply broken, and most liquid (from any forge mod) source blocks which are simply ignored just like a pick would. Lava however prevents the quarry from mining anything under it.

Comment: As far as I have seen a source block of some unknown fluid gets destroyed rather then neglected. I had my quarry get blocked on the flow of some sludge(from MFE I think) that was in the wall. It kept removing the flowblock, as in actually removing it, then the flow flowed back, and so on and so forth. Aside from water and lava I never had fluids left over in a pit either, while I'm quite certain they were there when the quarry started. Lava blocks progress just as bedrock does.